# How to denote a set of nested tuples?

Tags: notation

I want to define a set that elements that are nested tuples, like this one:

$$a =((1, 2), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2))$$

I want this so I can index elements and write $a_{2,3} = 3$.

My first idea was simply writing: $\mathbb{R}^2 × \mathbb{R}^3 × \mathbb{R}^2$.
But this equals $\mathbb{R}^7$. So the tuples it contains couldn't have two indexes.

Is there a notation I can use for tuples of tuples?

Comment: Do you think $((1,2),(1,2,3),(1,2))=(1,2,1,2,3,1,2)$? If not, then why do you say that $\Bbb R^2\times\Bbb R^3\times\Bbb R^2$ "equals" $\Bbb R^7$?

Comment: @blue The [wiki page on Tuples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple#Tuples_as_nested_ordered_pairs) makes me think that the parentheses can be ignored.

Comment: They can be, but do you see how my comment answers your question?

Answer (score 1):

$a$ is a vector of vectors, not necessarily from the same space.  Thus $a_i$ has it's conventional meaning of the $i$th component.  Then $a_{i,j}$ naturally has the meaning you want it to.  You could also use $a_{ijk\dots}$.  Also the two sets you mention are not equal, but isomorphic as many spaces eg. as real vector spaces.  They are probably homeomorphic too.